# Troubleshooting upgrade issues - On topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I have a question about a Wordpress installation I have on my own server at home. I can't upgrade the themes or plugins, without deleting them first. **Is this a question I can ask about here?** I realize it's not really a "development" question, but wanted to check before polluting the main site

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a server configuration question which...

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> WordPress Stack Exchange is for WordPress developers and
>   administrators to ask questions about:
>
> - theme and plugin development
> - development and management best practices
> - server configuration for WordPress
>
> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

... is on topic. But if something in the WordPress Core is causing the issue, then of course it would still be on topic.

It is possible that your particular plugins/themes are causing trouble, and that may not be on-topic, but without more detail I can't make that call.

Go ahead and ask your question, and provide as much detail as you can.